# Replace first occurence of desired word in HTML with another word

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace, cpu-word

Assume my HTML string is:

`<p>Example: This is my example string. This is one more Example sentence.</p>`

I want to replace first occurrence of desired word, in this case the word `example` with same word but wrapped with `strong` tag so the final string becomes:

`<p><strong>Example:</strong> This is my example string. This is one more Example sentence.</p>`

so when it renders, it becomes:

```
**Example:** This is my example string. This is one more Example sentence.
```

Comment: So what did you attempt?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `replace()` like the following way:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('p');
var word = 'Example:'
var output = el.textContent.replace(word, '<strong>'+word+'</strong>');
el.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<p>Example: This is my example string. This is one more Example sentence.</p>
```

You can also try RegEx with ***non-standard*** [$n with String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n#Using_n_with_String.replace):

```js
var el = document.querySelector('p');
var output = el.textContent.replace(/(Example:)/, '<strong>$1</strong>');
el.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<p>Example: This is my example string. This is one more Example sentence.</p>
```